# Override the layouts folder path with other folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.2, view

In the Rails application(version 3.2), the controller has to use conditional layouts based on different conditions inside a specific action.

```
  def index
   if dp_allowed?
    //use a different layout
   else
     //render diff layout
   end
  end
```

Now, i tried using

```
  layout :user_layout
   def user_layout
     if dp_allowed?
      "file1"
     else
      "file2"
     end
   end
```

The above code always expects the path after layouts folder as its relative to layouts folder. How can i use a path like `app/views/containers/users/_user_detail.html.erb`

EDIT:

```
 <div class="app-pane-header">
<div id="title" class="pane-title">
<%= yield :d_title %><%= yield :additional_title %></div>
<%= yield :details %>
```

This is the file1 in my case say, it works perfectly if i just use

```
  layout 'file1'
```

Comment: That looks like a partial.  Are you sure you don't just want to do `render :partial` instead? `render :partial` won't use a layout, it will just use that partial as the template.

Comment: @MaxWilliams no i'm clear on that. I want to use it like a layout. Please find the updated question which contains the layout file code

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an absolute path to your layout.  It's best to do it relative to your `Rails.root` folder so it will work locally and on the production box.  eg

```
layout File.join(Rails.root, "app/views/containers/users/_user_detail.html.erb")
```